# Peut-on dire « Je me plains de ne rien avoir reçu de satisfaisant en récompense de ma peine. »?

Tags: constructions, syntaxe

J’ai besoin de votre conseil sur l’ordre dans lequel j’ai mis les mots de cette phrase :

> Je me plains de ne rien avoir reçu de satisfaisant en récompense de ma
>   peine.

La façon d’utiliser « se plaindre de » et « en récompense de » me semble bonne quoique je soupçonne la dernière tournure d’être soutenue. Je doute d’ailleurs fort de l'ordre des mots du milieu de la phrase. J’espère que vous pouvez m’aider à mieux trier les mots si je me suis trompé.

Le but de cette question est de m’accoutumer à la façon avec laquelle l’on classe les parties d’une telle phrase. Si vous avez un autre exemple qui sonne mieux et fait pareillement ressortir la manière à laquelle on rédige une phrase de ce genre, alors cela m’intéresserait.

---

J’ai fait cette phrase pour mettre à l’épreuve mon aptitude à la rédiger, voilà pourquoi je ne peux rien dire sur le milieu dans lequel il se trouvait. Je l’ai cassé en morceaux avec d’autres formulations pour la certitude.

- Je me suis efforcé de quelque chose.
- Je n’ai rien reçu quelque chose en récompense.(pas forcément d'argent.)
- Je montre le déplaisir que j’en éprouve.

J’espère que ces renseignements vous permettent de dire plus. J’ai peur de m’éloigner du sujet de la question si je vous prie d’étudier le choix des mots, mais cela serait également très utile.

Comment: Je me plains à qui ? Qu'attendiez vous de satisfaisant ? De quelle "peine" s'agit-il ? Pas facile de proposer quelque chose d'idiomatique sans contexte

Comment: Je t'ai laissé un message http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18414478#18414478

Comment: La phrase est tout à fait correcte, dans un écrit littéraire ou juridique, et l'ordre est 'naturel'.

Comment: @Laure, Merci pour avoir retiré les fautes et pour m’avoir mis au courant à propos du chapeau de « vôtre »!

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais plutôt "je me plains de n'avoir rien reçu de satisfaisant en récompense de ma peine."